# If the metric space is $\mathbb Q$, is it connected?

Tags: general-topology

My idea:
I first observe its component, for example $\dfrac{3}{2}$. Then, I consider in a metric space $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that $\left\{\dfrac{3}{2}\right\}$ is relatively closed to $\mathbb{Q}$. However, the closure of $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\left\{\dfrac{3}{2}\right\}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$. It would become $\left\{\dfrac{3}{2}\right\}\cap\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\emptyset$.

I could not find out two closed set to disconnect the metric space $\mathbb{Q}$. Where am I wrong since intuitively $\mathbb{Q}$ is not connected in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: "intuitively Q isn't connected in R?" Why do you have that intuition? If you can exploit that more directly, it might be easier.

Comment: You are right $\mathbb Q\setminus\{3/2\}$ is not closed, so that won't quite work. Try to think using irrational numbers.

Comment: I have used irrational number in R. but  I think that I can't use irrational number in metric space Q

Comment: You don't have to use an irrational number **in** the metric space Q. But you can nonetheless use it to define **subsets** in Q.

Comment: Think of it this way: I can define the following subsets of $\mathbb Z$: $$A = \{n \in \mathbb Z \mid n >\frac{1}{2}\} = \{1,2,3,...\}, \qquad B = \{n \in \mathbb Z \mid n < \frac{1}{2}\} = \{...,-2,-1,0\}$$ It makes perfect sense to write those sets and work with them, *even though* $\frac{1}{2} \not\in \mathbb Z$. The reason this works is because $\mathbb Z$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ are both contained in a larger set where inequality is defined, namely $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I realize your idea. thank for everyone. All of your advice is great.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Q \cap (-\infty, \sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q \cap ( \sqrt 2,\infty)$ are closed and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb Q$ whose union is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: but if you are in metric space Q, it won't have irrational number.

Comment: @Andrew Set of all rational numbers less than $\sqrt 2$ (which is set of all negative rationals, zero, and those positive one's whose squares are less than $ 2$ is  awell defined subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I think I probably understand your thought. Both of them are closed in Q, but they are disjoint.

Comment: Write $A=\{ q \in \Bbb{Q} \mid q^2 < 2 \}$ to avoid using irrational numbers to define your clopen subsets.